# Compile an STM32 program on X86 Linux using TinyCC

Tags: ubuntu, arm, stm32, tcc

How can I install and configure TinyCC, then invoke the compiler and the linker to produce the `.bin` file that I can flash into my STM32 demo board? Please include specific steps. I am on Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64.

Comment: Any reason why you would not use a more standard/supported set of tools, such as [gcc-arm-none-eabi](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/9-2019q4/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2?revision=108bd959-44bd-4619-9c19-26187abf5225&la=en&hash=E788CE92E5DFD64B2A8C246BBA91A249CB8E2D2D) ?

Comment: probably educational purpose. I was using TCC for boot time kernel compilation :). Totally useless but good fun

Comment: @P__J__  If the goal is to tackle a challenging task, I can understand. However, requesting 'specific steps' does not fill well in this picture.

Comment: @exebook: What is exactly the demo board you are targeting ?

Comment: @Frant Bluepill

Comment: @Frant of course to learn and have fun. I love TinyC, it's small and fast and does a great job. What I cannot understand is how to make it cross compile to ARM from Linux x86_64. Then this .bin format is a mistery for me, to that's also to learn in the process.

Answer (score 1):

`TinyCC` was originally designed for building executable files in [ELF](https://linuxhint.com/understanding_elf_file_format/) format containing user-mode programs for Linux.It does support [Cortex-A](https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/processors/cortex-a) profile, but chances you can use it as is for cross-compiling for a [Cortex-M](https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/processors/cortex-m) STM32F103 are non-existent IMHO.

Here is what I would suggest:

- Keep TinyCC on the side for the time being, while you are learning about the STM32F103 using your Blue Pill board.
- Use the GCC toolchain referenced hereafter for explaining how the .bin can be produced. Once you will feel comfortable with  GCC and the STM32F103, you can go back to experimenting with TinyCC.

---

How to a create a`.bin` file from a C program for the STM32F103, and how it does relate to the corresponding ELF file:

- install git on your Ubuntu 19.10: `apt-get install git`
- create/choose a working directory: `mkdir bluepill`
- change your current working directory to bluepill: `cd bluepill`
- clone a nice, small example program available on `github`:
   `git clone https://github.com/satoshinm/pill_blink.git`
- Download/extract the GCC 9.2.1 toolchain for Cortex-M provided by arm:
  `wget "https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/9-2019q4/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2?revision=108bd959-44bd-4619-9c19-26187abf5225&la=en&hash=E788CE92E5DFD64B2A8C246BBA91A249CB8E2D2D" -O gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2`
  `tar Jxf gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2`
- add the toolchain bin directory to your current path:
  `export PATH=$(pwd)/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin:$PATH`
- verify gcc can be executed:
  `arm-none-eabi-gcc --version`

You should see:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599]
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

You can now build the example contained in the `pill_blink/bare-metal` directory:
`make -C pill_blink/bare-metal all`
You should have built an executable in ELF format, and a .bin containing only the code and the data that was built from the ELF file using `arm-none-eabi-objcopy` should now be available - please refer to `pill_blink/bare-metal/Makefile` for the exact command:

```
ls -gG pill_blink/bare-metal
total 72
-rw-rw-r-- 1   255 Mar 11 14:35 bluepill.ld
-rw-rw-r-- 1   483 Mar 11 14:35 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x 1   440 Mar 11 14:36 pill_blink.bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1  1059 Mar 11 14:35 pill_blink.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1    27 Mar 11 14:36 pill_blink.d
-rwxrwxr-x 1 82452 Mar 11 14:36 pill_blink.elf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 21528 Mar 11 14:36 pill_blink.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1   326 Mar 11 14:35 README.md
```

The ELF file does contain the compiled C program, along with a lot of metadata, as explained in the [ELF article](https://linuxhint.com/understanding_elf_file_format/) referenced above. You can use `arm-none-objdump` for exploring the .ELF file:

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -x pill_blink/bare-metal/pill_blink.elf 

pill_blink/bare-metal/pill_blink.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm
pill_blink/bare-metal/pill_blink.elf
architecture: armv7, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x08000151

Program Header:
    LOAD off    0x00010000 vaddr 0x08000000 paddr 0x08000000 align 2**16
         filesz 0x000001b8 memsz 0x000001b8 flags r-x
private flags = 5000200: [Version5 EABI] [soft-float ABI]

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         000001b8  08000000  08000000  00010000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .debug_info   0000017f  00000000  00000000  000101b8  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  2 .debug_abbrev 000000d4  00000000  00000000  00010337  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  3 .debug_aranges 00000020  00000000  00000000  0001040b  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  4 .debug_macro  00000a9b  00000000  00000000  0001042b  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  5 .debug_line   00000086  00000000  00000000  00010ec6  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  6 .debug_str    00002dfb  00000000  00000000  00010f4c  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  7 .comment      00000079  00000000  00000000  00013d47  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  8 .ARM.attributes 0000002d  00000000  00000000  00013dc0  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  9 .debug_frame  00000020  00000000  00000000  00013df0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
SYMBOL TABLE:
08000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l    d  .debug_info    00000000 .debug_info
00000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  00000000 .debug_abbrev
00000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 00000000 .debug_aranges
00000000 l    d  .debug_macro   00000000 .debug_macro
00000000 l    d  .debug_line    00000000 .debug_line
00000000 l    d  .debug_str     00000000 .debug_str
00000000 l    d  .comment       00000000 .comment
00000000 l    d  .ARM.attributes        00000000 .ARM.attributes
00000000 l    d  .debug_frame   00000000 .debug_frame
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 pill_blink.c
08000150  w    F .text  00000068 reset_handler
08000000 g     O .text  00000150 vector_table

arm-none-eabi-objdump -d pill_blink/bare-metal/pill_blink.elf

pill_blink/bare-metal/pill_blink.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <vector_table>:
 8000000:       00 00 00 00 51 01 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     ....Q...........
        ...

08000150 <reset_handler>:
 8000150:       4b13            ldr     r3, [pc, #76]   ; (80001a0 <reset_handler+0x50>)
 8000152:       681b            ldr     r3, [r3, #0]
 8000154:       4a12            ldr     r2, [pc, #72]   ; (80001a0 <reset_handler+0x50>)
 8000156:       f043 0310       orr.w   r3, r3, #16
 800015a:       6013            str     r3, [r2, #0]
 800015c:       4b11            ldr     r3, [pc, #68]   ; (80001a4 <reset_handler+0x54>)
 800015e:       4a11            ldr     r2, [pc, #68]   ; (80001a4 <reset_handler+0x54>)
 8000160:       681b            ldr     r3, [r3, #0]
 8000162:       6013            str     r3, [r2, #0]
 8000164:       4b0f            ldr     r3, [pc, #60]   ; (80001a4 <reset_handler+0x54>)
 8000166:       681b            ldr     r3, [r3, #0]
 8000168:       4a0e            ldr     r2, [pc, #56]   ; (80001a4 <reset_handler+0x54>)
 800016a:       f443 1300       orr.w   r3, r3, #2097152        ; 0x200000
 800016e:       6013            str     r3, [r2, #0]
 8000170:       4b0d            ldr     r3, [pc, #52]   ; (80001a8 <reset_handler+0x58>)
 8000172:       f44f 5200       mov.w   r2, #8192       ; 0x2000
 8000176:       601a            str     r2, [r3, #0]
 8000178:       2400            movs    r4, #0
 800017a:       e001            b.n     8000180 <reset_handler+0x30>
 800017c:       bf00            nop
 800017e:       3401            adds    r4, #1
 8000180:       4b0a            ldr     r3, [pc, #40]   ; (80001ac <reset_handler+0x5c>)
 8000182:       429c            cmp     r4, r3
 8000184:       ddfa            ble.n   800017c <reset_handler+0x2c>
 8000186:       4b0a            ldr     r3, [pc, #40]   ; (80001b0 <reset_handler+0x60>)
 8000188:       f44f 5200       mov.w   r2, #8192       ; 0x2000
 800018c:       801a            strh    r2, [r3, #0]
 800018e:       2400            movs    r4, #0
 8000190:       e001            b.n     8000196 <reset_handler+0x46>
 8000192:       bf00            nop
 8000194:       3401            adds    r4, #1
 8000196:       4b07            ldr     r3, [pc, #28]   ; (80001b4 <reset_handler+0x64>)
 8000198:       429c            cmp     r4, r3
 800019a:       ddfa            ble.n   8000192 <reset_handler+0x42>
 800019c:       e7e8            b.n     8000170 <reset_handler+0x20>
../..
```

Now, using, say, `hexdump`, for displaying the content of the .bin file, you will be able to correlate this content with the content of the ELF file:

```
hexdump -C  pill_blink/bare-metal/pill_blink.bin
00000000  00 00 00 00 51 01 00 08  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....Q...........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000150  13 4b 1b 68 12 4a 43 f0  10 03 13 60 11 4b 11 4a  |.K.h.JC....`.K.J|
00000160  1b 68 13 60 0f 4b 1b 68  0e 4a 43 f4 00 13 13 60  |.h.`.K.h.JC....`|
00000170  0d 4b 4f f4 00 52 1a 60  00 24 01 e0 00 bf 01 34  |.KO..R.`.$.....4|
00000180  0a 4b 9c 42 fa dd 0a 4b  4f f4 00 52 1a 80 00 24  |.K.B...KO..R...$|
00000190  01 e0 00 bf 01 34 07 4b  9c 42 fa dd e8 e7 00 bf  |.....4.K.B......|
000001a0  18 10 02 40 04 10 01 40  10 10 01 40 3f 42 0f 00  |...@...@...@?B..|
000001b0  14 10 01 40 1f a1 07 00                           |...@....|
000001b8
```

Since the `.bin` file is supposed to be flashed verbatim at address `0x08000000`, that means you can correlate the content of addresses `0x00000000` and `0x00000150` of the `hexdump` output
with the output of the `arm-none-eabi-objdump -d` command, but at addresses `0x08000000+0x00000000` and `0x08000000+0x00000150`, i.e. `0x08000000` and `0x08000150`.

I hope this does answer your question.